# Gedmo Tree didn't manage implement it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tree

i'm trying to make a category / menu dynamic to update the links and everything from admin panel. I tried implementing Tree from gedmo but couldn't get the children even after i spend hours looking over the documentation. Also i want to use knp menu bundle.
Can someone help me out to implement it and explain to me what is with lft, rgt, root, level from tree and why should i use when should i use them ?

Here's my method :

```
public function createAdminMenu(array $options)
{
    $menu_item = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:MenuItem');
    $menu = $this->factoryInterface->createItem('root');

    $rootNodes = $menu_item->getRootNodes();

    //var_dump($rootNodes);
    $node = $menu_item->findOneByName('User');
    var_dump($menu_item->getChildren());
    foreach($rootNodes as $node) {
        if($node->getDisplay())
        {
            $menu->addChild($node->getName(), array('uri' => $node->getUri()));

            $child_node = $node->getChildren($node);
            //var_dump($child_node);
            foreach($child_node as $child)
            {
                //$menu[$node->getName()] = $menu->addChild($child->getName());
            }
        }
    }


    return $menu;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:MenuItem');

    $nodes = $repo->findByRootNodes($menuId);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if ($node->getDisplay()) {
            $menu->addChild($node->getName(), ['uri' => $node->getRoute()])
                ->setAttribute('dropdown', $node->getDropDown());
            if ($node->getDisplayChildren()) {
                $children = $repo->children($node);
                if($children)
                {
                    foreach ($children as $child)
                    {
                        if ($child->getDisplay())
                        {
                            $menu[$node->getName()]->addChild($child->getName(), ['uri' => $child->getRoute()])
                                ->setAttribute('divider_prepend', $child->getDividerPrepend())
                                ->setAttribute('divider_append', $child->getDividerAppend());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $menu;
```